# React: Fetching data after `componentDidMount`

Tags: reactjs

I have a general question about good practice for React data fetching.

In general, all of the tutorials I have read suggest fetching data in `componentDidMount`. So my lifecycle looks like this

```
render
componentDidMount
    fetch ... setState
render
```

Now I have buttons which, when clicked, should fetch more data. But `componentDidMount` will not be called again. So what is the best practice for calling `fetch` again after `componentDidMount` has already been called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to put the `fecth` call in `componentDidMount`. You can put your fetch in a function outside of `componentDidMount`, and call it in `componentDidMount` and call it again after any button action.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchApi();
  }
fetchApi = () => {
   //call fetch
}
```

Comment: Ok. That's what I was going to do. I just wasn't sure what problems (if any) that would introduce.

Comment: No, it is good to fetch after `componentDidMount` because you can handle your loading state while data's are fetching, but nobody said that you have to keep your fetch function inside `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount works only one time in component lifecycle - after first render when component is mounting. As I understand, you you need fetch more data by button clicking, so you need something like this:

```
async loadData() {
   const processedResponse = await fetchAsyncFunction()
   this.setState ({yourStateParam: processedResponse })
```

...

```
render(){
   return(
      <button onClick={this.loadData}
   )
}
```